# Ошибка при прошивке ядра CM0+ контроллера на отладочной плате NUCLEO STM32WL55JC2

Tags: c, stm32, микроконтроллеры, stm32cubeide

Использую отладочную плату **NUCLEO STM32WL55JC2**.

Скачал тестовый проект, предоставленный самими STM. Использую CubeIDE. При прошивке ядра CM4 - никаких проблем не возникает, а при прошивке CM0+ получаю сообщение, как на скрине. Подскажите, с чем может быть связано?

[image]

```
>STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 6.0.0
>Copyright (c) 2021, STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.
>
>Starting server with the following options:
>        Persistent Mode            : Disabled
>        Logging Level              : 1
>        Listen Port Number         : 61235
>        Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
>        Verbose Mode               : Disabled
>        SWD Debug                  : Enabled
>
>Target unknown error 32
>
>
>Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
>Reason: Unknown. Please check power and cabling to target.


>Error in final launch sequence:
>
>Failed to start GDB server
>Failed to start GDB server
>Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
>Reason: (255) Unknown. Please check power and cabling to target.
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Возможно, проблема в перемычках. Программатор не видит контроллер.

Comment: Нашел информацию в ролике от STM, что cm0+ в проекте нужно включать отдельно. Нашел функцию, которая его включает, вроде бы все супер. Но включить отладку например, прошить ядро или удостовериться, что cm0+ действительно завелось я не могу.